# Global SSH key, working for root user but not for other users

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys, sshd

I am trying to set up a global ssh key, that will allow me to log into any account with just one key.

So far added a global directory `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys` to the Authorized_Keys section of the `sshd_config` file. 
I am now able to log in as a root user using the global key, but I am unable to log in as any other user using the global key.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant parts of the sshd_config file. It would also be helpful to run "ls -la /etc/ssh/authorized_keys" and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I don't know who deleted the first reply but the person was partly correct.
 It was a permissions problem, though instead of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` having the wrong permissions,
 it was the `/etc/ssh/authorized_keys` which had the wrong permissions.
 It had permissions `700` instead of `644` so I changed it back. Sorry if my formatting is wrong this is like legit my first post ever.
 Also thank you to the kind stranger, who said it was a permissions problem